# Not only, but also (in cantonese)

Tags: grammar, cantonese, nuance

> 佢唔單只感冒，仲發燒添。
>   Not only does he have a cold, but he also has a fever.

What is the function of 添？ I feel rather awkward saying it. I searched the dictionary and doesn’t look like it has added any meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in these notes from *ABC Cantonese* on the word 添:

> 1 more
>
> 畀多我一百蚊
>   bei2 do1 ngo5 jat1 baat3 man1 tim1
>   Give me one hundred dollars more
>
> 食多啲
>   sik6 do1 di1 tim1
>   Eat some more
>
> Notes: occurs at end of sentence to indicate action is expected to be repeated; usually pronunciation with high falling tone; also written as 㖭 tim1, 添 tim1
>
> 2 as well, also, more, again
>
> 佢撞到人唔道歉,仲鬧人
>   keoi5 zong6 dou2 jan4 m4 dou6 hip3, zung6 naau6 jan4 tim1
>   After bumping into somebody, he didn't apologize, and even scolded that person as well
>
> 噉做法仲弊
>   gam2 zou6 faat3 zung6 bai6 tim1
>   Doing it this way is also even worse
>
> Notes: follows 仲 zung6 to emphasize something additional is involved

Answer (score 2):

仲 = also

添 = add / additionally

[(**仲**) ~ (**添**)] is a set structure for [(**in addition, also**) ~ ]

仲發燒添 means "in addition, also have fever"

Answer (score 2):

添 can be optional. It's used to exaggerate his expression. You can say `佢唔單只感冒，仲發燒`